# Cursor Focus on Textbox in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am currently in the process of creating a Onscreen keyboard. I am handling the button click using routedcommands. The issue is that when i click on the button in keyboard panel the focus shifts to the button rather than on the Textbox. The requirement states that a cursor should always appear in the text box to indicate the position where the next character will be inserted. Is there a way i can keep focus on the textbox while button is clicked.

Answer (score 37):

To set logical focus to an input control

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, textboxJack);     // set logical focus
```

To set keyboard focus to an input control

```
Keyboard.Focus(textboxJill);                             // set keyboard focus
```

To know the difference between logical and keyboard focus

[Input Overview - Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#focus) on MSDN

Answer (score 13):

Get the reference for the specific control(in that case TextBox). After click, in Button_Click method paste this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
            {
                control.Focus();
            });
```

Comment: Why is this working when the others don't? Aren't we already on the UI thread? Why the delegate?

Answer (score 8):

I like these do-my-homework-for-me questions; "the requirement states"...priceless. For those who find this via Google, the trick to progmatically moving the cursor in a WPF TextBox is to use the SelectioNStart property.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Focus();
    textBox.SelectionStart = textName.Text.Length;
}
```

Comment: This is not a "do-my-homework-for-me" question. It is a "I am doing my homework, but I am stuck, can somebody give me some pointers" question.

Answer (score 3):

```
Textbox.Focus();
```

this will focus on the textbox

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved this problem was to set `focusable=false` to all the buttons/controls on the keyboard. That way you don't lose focused of the current control.

Comment: This is a better approach but it sets the cursor position back at the beginning of the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved by using a separate focus scope for your "keyboard". Just apply the following property to the control that contains all of your buttons and then they will be in a separate focus scope and will not have the focus set to them when clicked

```
FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to use this to get my desired result

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, UserNameautoCompleteBox);

Key key = Key.Enter;                    // Key to send
var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;    // Target element
RoutedEvent routedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent; // Event to send

target.RaiseEvent(
    new KeyEventArgs(
        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
        PresentationSource.FromVisual(UserNameautoCompleteBox),
        0,
        key) { RoutedEvent = routedEvent }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing, but nothing seemed to work for me. I really needed an answer that worked purely in XAML as I'm working with MVVM.

I finally found this example:
http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/03/06/xaml-wpf-textbox-focus/

and modified it to this:

In the 'Resources' section:

```
    <Style x:Key="FocusTextBox" TargetType="Grid">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBoxName, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=textBoxName}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

In my grid definition:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource FocusTextBox}" />
```