# move into next field webbrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am using a web browser control in wpf to load a web page. I need to  have a wpf button which  when clicked will help the user to move next input field, The web page have two text box and two radio buttons as input fields. How can i simulate this when the wpf button is clicked?

Comment: Are you talking about to set focus on the next input filed?

Comment: Yes,to set focus on the next input filed

Answer (score 0):

To set focus on a WPF textbox you can do as following. (Possible duplicate : [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828155/cursor-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-c))

To set logical focus to an input control

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, textboxJack);     // set logical focus
```

To set keyboard focus to an input control

```
Keyboard.Focus(textboxJill);                             // set keyboard focus
```